# Declaring a dictionary of lists

Tags: vim

Is it at all possible to create a dictionary that maps strings to lists?
Something like this:

```
let dict = {"java" : {"1", "2", ... }}
```

Which could be accessed like so

```
" Returns {"1", "2"}
dict["java"]
```

Here are the errors emitted by vim when evaluating the first code snippet:

> line    1: E720: Missing colon in Dictionary: , "2"}}
>
> E15: Invalid expression: {"java" : {"1", "2"}}

Comment: let dict = {"java" : ["1", "2"]}

Comment: @yolenoyer post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace it like this:

```
let dict = {"java" : ["1", "2"]}
```

`{}` structures make dictionnaries, and `[]` structures make lists, it's quite similar in Python.

Note: to build big structures, you have to add a `\` at the **beginning** of each additionnal line, i.e:

```
let dict = {
\    "java" : [
\         "1",
\         "2"
\    ]
\}
```

See `:h list`, `:h dict`